# Having-clicks inside RecyclerAdapter on my Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I was trying to make responsive clicks events inside my RecyclerAdapter. I can't understand the logic behind on it since my data is auto created by API, therefore i have some buttons in my list and I've like to have response by clicking on it.

This is my code:

My Adapter class:

```
    public class EppViewCartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EppViewCartAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        View itemView;
        ImageView add,less;
        private List<EppViewCartDetails> orderData;

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView subject,category,brand,neww,newd,old,discount,count,color;
            ImageView image;


            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                subject=view.findViewById(R.id.view_cart_item_subject);
                category=view.findViewById(R.id.view_cart_item_category);
                brand=view.findViewById(R.id.view_cart_item_brand);
                neww=view.findViewById(R.id.view_cart_item_neww);
                old=view.findViewById(R.id.view_cart_item_old);
                discount=view.findViewById(R.id.view_cart_item_discount);
                newd=view.findViewById(R.id.view_cart_item_new_depends_count);
                count=view.findViewById(R.id.view_cart_item_count);
                image=view.findViewById(R.id.view_cart_item_image);
                add=itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_btn_add);
                less=itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_btn_less);

            }
        }

        public EppViewCartAdapter(List<EppViewCartDetails> preorderList) {
            this.orderData = preorderList;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.view_cart_card_view, parent, false);

            //TODO: I was trying to make a set onlcick  listener here but it has errors.
            add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Add Click response properly.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            EppViewCartDetails data= orderData.get(position);

            double amount = Double.parseDouble(data.getCount())*Double.parseDouble(data.getNeww());
            DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");

            holder.subject.setText(data.getSubject());
            holder.category.setText(data.getCategory());
            holder.brand.setText(data.getBrand());
            holder.neww.setText("₱ "+formatter.format(amount));
            holder.newd.setText(data.getNewd());
            holder.old.setText(data.getOld());
            holder.old.setPaintFlags(holder.old.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            holder.discount.setText(data.getDiscount());
            holder.count.setText(data.getCount());



            Picasso.with(itemView.getContext()).load("https://eppteststorage.blob.core.windows.net/images/"+data.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.small_logo).into(holder.image, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            Log.e("tae tae"," PAkultie");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                        }
                    }
            );


        }


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return orderData.size();
        }

    }
```

My error trying my OnclickEvent:(upon my //TODO:)

```
   Process: eppmobile.intellismart.com.EPP, PID: 18675
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at eppmobile.intellismart.com.EPP.ViewCart.EppViewCartAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(EppViewCartAdapter.java:58)
        at eppmobile.intellismart.com.EPP.ViewCart.EppViewCartAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(EppViewCartAdapter.java:22)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
```

My Activity class:

```
    public class EppViewCart extends Fragment {
        View inflatedView = null;
        EppViewCartDetails items;
        private List<EppViewCartDetails> dataitems = new ArrayList<>();

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_epp_view_cart, container, false);
            retriveSQLITE();


            return inflatedView;
        }

        private void retriveSQLITE() {
            SqLiteDB sql = new SqLiteDB(getContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = sql.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor c = sql.retrieveAddToCart(db);
            ArrayList<AddToCartModel> get = new ArrayList<>();
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                final AddToCartModel details = new AddToCartModel();
                details.setID(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ID")));
                details.setDateTime(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DateTime")));
                details.setID_ProductMasterListV(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ID_ProductMasterListV")));
                details.setImageFile(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ImageFile")));
                details.setOrdered(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Ordered")));
                get.add(details);

                APICaller service = EppMainFragmentPropertyClient.getRetrofit().create(APICaller.class);
                View_Response gets = new View_Response("1", details.getID(), details.getID_ProductMasterListV());
                Call<List<View_Data_Properties>> call = service.getView(gets);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<List<View_Data_Properties>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<View_Data_Properties>> call, Response<List<View_Data_Properties>> response) {

                        //Discount
                        String q = String.format("%.2f", Double.parseDouble(response.body().get(0).getLess()));
                        long l = Math.round(Double.parseDouble(q));
                        String percent = l + "%";

                        double amount = Double.parseDouble(response.body().get(0).getNewPrice());
                        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");

                        double amount2 = Double.parseDouble(response.body().get(0).getSRP());
                        DecimalFormat formatter2 = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");

                        items = new EppViewCartDetails(
                                response.body().get(0).getID(),
                                response.body().get(0).getName(),
                                response.body().get(0).getCategory(),
                                response.body().get(0).getProductsBrand(),
                                response.body().get(0).getNewPrice(),
                                "₱ " + formatter.format(amount),
                                "₱ " + formatter2.format(amount2),
                                "-" + percent,
                                details.getOrdered(), response.body().get(0).getHexValue(),
                                response.body().get(0).getImageFile());
                        dataitems.add(items);

                        prepareItems();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<View_Data_Properties>> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });


            }

        }

        private void prepareItems() {
            //Items
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            RecyclerView recyclerView = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.view_cart_recycler);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            EppViewCartAdapter mAdapter = new EppViewCartAdapter(dataitems);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }

    }
```

My CardView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/radius_all_two"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="190dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bestseller"
        android:id="@+id/view_cart_item_image"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="JBL- Grip 100"
        android:id="@+id/view_cart_item_subject"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Category"
        android:textColor="#089bcc"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Headphones"
        android:id="@+id/view_cart_item_category"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Brand"
        android:textColor="#089bcc"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="JBL"
        android:id="@+id/view_cart_item_brand"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="P 1,290.00"
        android:id="@+id/view_cart_item_neww"
        android:textColor="#00c1ab"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="83dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="P 2,580.00"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:id="@+id/view_cart_item_old"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="106dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="- 50%"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:id="@+id/view_cart_item_discount"
        android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
        android:textColor="#ba0101"
        android:layout_marginTop="106dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="P 1,290.00"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:id="@+id/view_cart_item_new_depends_count"
        android:layout_marginTop="123dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="x"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginTop="123dp"/>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="17dp"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:src="@drawable/left_arrow"
        android:text="x"
        android:id="@+id/view_cart_item_increment"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="123dp"/>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="17dp"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"
        android:text="x"
        android:id="@+id/view_cart_item_decrement"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="304dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="123dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="31dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:textSize="11dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="100"
            android:id="@+id/view_cart_item_count"
            android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="123dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Color"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:textColor="#089bcc"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="147dp"/>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/view_cart_variant"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_marginLeft="175dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="145dp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Cart_view :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0aM9.png)

(if you see the "<" and ">" sign, I was trying to add responsive there but it is running in RecyclerView with my adapter so that I didn't know if where could I put my onclick-event.)

My View in recyclerview(I set into comment my //TODO:)
(It is running but no fuction on add and subtract.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ucqq.jpg)

Also, I've try this to (holder.add.setOn...)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6snAo.png)

And this:(MyViewHolder)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bh6E.png)

Answer (score -1):

This is null pointer exception you need to understand.
you should replace `itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_btn_add)` with `view.findViewById(R.id.view_btn_add)`

because the adapter layout name is `view` not `itemview`

just look your code

```
 public MyViewHolder(View view) {
      super(view);
}
```

and you need add click listener either  in `MyViewHolder()` or in `onBindViewHolder()`

move this code

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Add Click response properly.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Ive try to change it like this view.findViewById(R.id.view_btn_add); but its the same error again.

Comment: what do you mean sir? sorry, i had test a lot but i can't figure why i was getting an error on my code. also I am learning on it since this is my first encounter in my development.

Comment: can you post your xml layout (R.layout.view_cart_card_view) here

Comment: dude you dont have any view with this id R.id.view_btn_add in xml view

Answer (score -1):

The crash is occurs because you are setting click listener on null `add` view.

First of check your layout file for the all defined IDs in MyViewHolder class. i can't find `view_btn_add` id in your layout file. So assign it with appropriate view.

And then in your onCreateViewHolder method, you are setting up onClick listener on `add` view before initialising it.

So move your `add.setOnClickListener(...)` inside `MyViewHolder` class after defining all views. So your crash will gone.

Comment: Ive try this too, on MyViewHolder(View view){

            add=view.findViewById(R.id.view_btn_add);
            less=view.findViewById(R.id.view_btn_less);


//and this code here


  add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Add Click response properly.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}



but it cause error again as null

Comment: must check my edit sir, ive been uploaded an attachment :)

Comment: Can you please update your question after moving click method inside MyViewHolder class?

Comment: ive just attache a file sir on my question.. (bottom image)
code + error attached sir :)

Comment: Yes, I have checked. It seems like it should be works. So please check the ID of the view `add` in your layout file. Is it match with id in adapter?

Comment: I've check my layout, it setted as Imageview, also i wass call it too as Imageview... but it calls the error as null.

Comment: hey @PAkultie I have checked your code, I haven't found any view with id `view_btn_add`. So assign this id with appropriate view.

Comment: yeah ive see it

Comment: Is that help you to identify your issue?

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer, in my other view cart data, there are the same ID in my xml so that ive just rename my buttons in my xml and inherit it on my class.

My viewCart:

```
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="17dp"
            android:layout_height="17dp"
            android:src="@drawable/left_arrow"
            android:text="x"
            android:id="@+id/view_cart_item_increment1"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="123dp"/>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="17dp"
            android:layout_height="17dp"
            android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"
            android:text="x"
            android:id="@+id/view_cart_item_decrement1"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="304dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="123dp"/>
```

My Adapter:

```
 @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.view_cart_card_view, parent, false);
        add=itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_cart_item_increment1);
        less=itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_cart_item_decrement1);



        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        EppViewCartDetails data= orderData.get(position);
  add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Add Click response properly.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
}
```